Get UYU Exchange Rate from API
I have this function that is supposed to extract the exchange rate from the following page and return it as a value. The problem is that for some reason I don't know it can't capture the value.
double getExchangeRate()
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    struct MemoryStruct chunk;
    chunk.memory = malloc(1);
    chunk.size = 0;

    double exchangeRate = 0.0;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://open.er-api.com/v6/latest/USD");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

        // Make the request
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() falue: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Response length: %zu\n", chunk.size);
            printf("API response: %s\n", chunk.memory);

            // Find the UYU exchange rate in the answer
            char *start = strstr(chunk.memory, "\"UYU\":");
            if (start)
            {
                start += 6; // Move the pointer after "\"UYU\":"
                exchangeRate = strtod(start, &start); //
                printf("Exchange rate obtained: %.2f\n", exchangeRate);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("The UYU exchange rate was not found in the response.\n");
            }
        }
        free(chunk.memory);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();

    return exchangeRate;
}


as you've only shown bits of your code  ... here's a trivial example to retrieve and scan rates ,  printing if found
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

char resultsBuff[8192*4] = {0}; // Buffer for response, populated in the callback fn

size_t callbackWr(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) {
    size_t total_size = size * nmemb;
    char *buffer = (char *)userp;
    strncat(buffer, (char *)contents, total_size);
    return total_size;
}

double scanResults( char *curr )
{
    char currBuff[80];
    char *start;
    char *endOf;
    char *rates;
    char thisRate[80];
    double rate=0.0;

    rates = strstr( resultsBuff, "\"rates\":" );//scan only the 'rates' bit
    if ( rates == NULL )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "no rates found in [%s]\n", resultsBuff );
        exit(1);
    }

    sprintf(currBuff, "\"%s\"", curr );
    start = strstr(rates, currBuff);
    if ( start )
    {
        endOf=strstr(start, "," );
        if ( endOf == NULL )
                endOf=strstr(start, "}" );   // if its the last currency ...

        if ( endOf != NULL )
                strncpy( thisRate, start, endOf - start );
    }

    if ( start == NULL || endOf == NULL )
        fprintf( stderr, "no exchange rate found for [%s]\n", curr );
    else{
        sscanf( strstr(thisRate,":")+1, "%lf", &rate );//convert to double
    }

    return rate;
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    char currency[20];
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    if ( argc == 2 )
        strcpy( currency, argv[1] );
    else{
    printf( "usage: %s currency\n", argv[0] );
    exit(1);
    }

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://open.er-api.com/v6/latest/USD");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callbackWr );
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, resultsBuff);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if(res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "Request failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        else
            fprintf( stdout, "%lf\n", scanResults( currency )); // print if a rate exists for this currency
        
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return 0;
}

# running that against the following
for rate in EUR XDF XPF YER ZAR USD GBP YEN JPY BSD USD AZN GIP HKD; do
./curly $rate
done
0.951373
no exchange rate found for [XDF]
0.000000
113.529106
250.309638
18.105199
1.000000
0.789299
no exchange rate found for [YEN]
0.000000
149.590682
1.000000
1.000000
1.700252
0.789298
7.782972


The idea is that after finding the string UYU, you would loop over to the value, capture it, and return it. It would be a function, not a procedure.

the conversion should've been easy for you ... however, i've amended to show one way to do that. programming is also about research/experimentation/learning from 'errors' etc. happy code.
